# Divisors of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a non-constant polynomial where $p$ is a prime that is not a divisor of the leading coefficient of $f$.

Assume that $f = g_{1}g_{2},\ldots, g_{k}$ is a factorization of $f$ into a product of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (i.e., all $g_i \in Z_p[x]$ and $f$ is viewed as a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_p$) and let $h$ be any divisor of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

**I need to prove that some $g_i$ is a divisor of $h$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.**

---

This is my attempt so far:

> If $h$ is a divisor of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, then $\exists k \in
> \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f = h \cdot k$.
>
> Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming that $f$ can be
>   considered the same polynomial over both $\mathbb{Z}$ and
>   $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ here, unless when we say that "$h$ is a divisor of
>   $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}$", we mean that it is the divisor of the image of
>   $f$ (call it $\tilde{f}$) under a map that takes $f$ from
>   $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}$, which we know is not a function. In
>   this case, then we have that $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that
>   $\tilde{f}= h \cdot k$.
>
> Then, reducing $\tilde{f} \mod p$ we obtain that $f = \overline{h}
> \cdot \overline{k}$, where $\overline{h}$ is  $\,h\mod p\,$ and
>    $\overline{k}$ is $k$ reduced modulo $p$.
>
> Now, we know that $f = \overline{h} \cdot \overline{k} = g_1 g_2
>  \cdots g_k$. But, all this tells me is that some $g_i$ is a
>    divisor of the product of $h$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $k$ over
>    $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

---

**At this point, I get completely stuck.**

It's entirely possible that this is not the correct way to approach this problem. If someone could help me figure out the right way to do this, I would be most appreciative!

Thank you for your time and petience!

Also, could be related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335209/f-irreducible-over-mathbbz-p-implies-f-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq?rq=1) question.

Comment: @Typhon I edited the question and subject line to give you that context.

Comment: @Typhon it's possible that my entire approach is wrong.

Comment: @Typhon fantastic. Well, thank you for looking anyway.

Comment: The $g_i$ are irreducible, hence prime.  If a prime divides a product, what else can you say?  If no prime divides an element, then it's a unit.

Comment: @sharding4 if a prime divides a product, then it must divide one of the divisors?

Comment: Do you know that a polynomial ring over a field is a UFD?

Comment: @BillDubuque yes, I am familar with that result. How does that help me, though? I mean other than telling me that $f = \overline{h} \cdot \overline{k} = g_{1}g_{2}\cdots g_{k}$ is the only way to factor $f$, so...

Comment: By uniqueness $\bar h$ is some (sub)product of the $g_i$ (upto units), and $\bar h$ is not a unit, so at least one $g_i$ occurs.

Comment: @BillDubuque probably the stupidest question ever, but how do we know that $\overline{h}$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$?

Comment: Leading coefficient hypothesis

Comment: @sharding4 awwwwrrr. Of course. Thanks. *told you it was stupid*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are talking about [cyclotomic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field). Those are obtained by joining a primitive $n$th root of unity to $Q$ the field of rational numbers. The $n$th cyclotomic field is referred to as $Q_n$. It is referred to $Z_n$ in your question. The answer is simple, all polynomials $P(x)$ that define the same field as $Q_x$, prime (powers) $p^k$ dividing $P(x)$ must have the form $1$ $\pmod n$. I don't know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: not really what I was looking for, no. Cyclotomic fields are a little too advanced for where I'm at in the course. But, I pretty much figured out the answer from all the hints above, so don't worry about it.