# $f$ being irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ implies all equivalent polynomials of $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ will be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$f$   being irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ implies all equivalent polynomials of $f$  in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ will be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$

I think $p$ is supposed to be a prime for the only following reason. I am explaining the reason by taking $p =10$.

If $p = 10$ then the statement would not be true for the element $10$..Because $10$ is a reducible element in $ \mathbb Z$ but so is not in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

I think this is the only reason we suppose $p$ a prime number.

Am I correct? Is there any other reason? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is $f$ required to be monic?

Comment: @Arthur  If it is, then the above implication is also true for non-prime $p$

Comment: In $\Bbb{Z/nZ}[x]$ you need to restrict to the factorization in monic polynomials or at least those with unit leading coefficient (otherwise $(2 x+1)^2 = 1 \bmod 4$ and no polynomial is irreducible). With this definition of irreducibility then yes a (monic) polynomial $\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible iff it is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z/nZ}[x]$ for some $n$.

Comment: I do not know the correct statement....Should the polynomial be monic in this statement? I have followed this statement  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335209/f-irreducible-over-mathbbz-p-implies-f-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq@Arthur

Comment: I also think the polynomial has to be monic because $2x$ is  irreducible in $\mathbb Z_3[x]$ but so is not in $\mathbb Z[x]$....@Arthur

Comment: "" you need to restrict to the factorization in monic polynomials or at least those with unit leading coefficient""                                          Is there any difference between Monic Polynomial and a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$  ?   @reuns

Comment: Have I gone wrong anywhere in the attempt of my question?  @Peter

Comment: I have made little changes in the statement ...Can you please go through it one more time and tell me if it is right or wrong? @Arthur

Comment: @cmi Nothing wrong, I only wanted to extend Arthurs comment. And I think, the comments clarified when we can use $\mathbb Z_n$ and when not.